# NoMethodError in Sitecities#index when using will_paginate with scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, will-paginate

I am still very new to ruby on rails and I have tried for hours to figure this out but couldn't. I think my scope might be the source of the problem. Can you help me find out how to fix this?

I have two models, sitecity.rb and event.rb. An event belongs_to a sitecity and a sitecity has_many events.

On my sitecities index page, I want to only show sitecities in which there is at least one event. Therefore I created a scope in sitecities.rb:

```
scope :has_event, ->(n = 1) { includes(:events).select { |w| w.events.size >= n } }
```

My sitecities index file contains:

```
<%= will_paginate @sitecities.has_event %><br />
```

My sitecities controller index action:

```
def index
  @sitecities = Sitecity.order("name asc").page(params[:page]).per_page(20)
```

This is the error I get:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `total_pages' for #<Array:0x00000100d26008>):
21: 
22: <br />
23: 
24: <%= will_paginate @sitecities.germany.has_event %><br />
25: 
26: 
27: <h2> <%=t :cities_austria %> </h2>
app/views/sitecities/index.html.erb:24:in `_app_views_sitecities_index_html_erb___1333285971746927117_2155045900'
app/controllers/sitecities_controller.rb:11:in `index'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a

```
require 'will_paginate/array'
```

before the code that causes the problem, or in your application controller

EDIT

You could also try changing your controller action to:

```
def index
  @sitecities = Sitecity.order("name asc").paginate(:page => params[:page],
                                                    :per_page => 20)
end
```

Make sure you have the latest version of will_paginate

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I still get the same error.

Comment: I updated to will_paginate (3.0.5). I also changed the controller as suggested, but still get the same error.